# take certain elements from an array

Tags: matlab, double, sparse-matrix

is there an easy way to select let's say every 2 elements from an array taking the first nonzero element. My array is sparse double. For example:

```
val =

     (1,1)             0.1667
     (2,1)             0.1667
     (3,1)             0.1667
     (4,1)             0.1667
     (5,1)             0.1667
     (6,1)             0.1667
     (7,1)             0.1667
     (8,1)             0.1667
```

So I want to run my code taking 2 values in, next two values out and so on.
Like this:

```
val = 
     (1,1)             0.1667
     (2,1)             0.1667
     (5,1)             0.1667
     (6,1)             0.1667
```

Below is my code, let's say I want to select every 2 elements starting from the first nonzero element.

```
results=zeros(86400,1); % time of the day in seconds
for i=1:28,
    currentFlowArray=allFileMin(i).demand_pattern1.Wm.total.flowArray;
    for p=1:86400,
        results(p)=results(p)+ currentFlowArray(p);
    end
end
```

Hope I was clear!
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the values out of `val`:

```
valnz = nonzeros(val);
result = valnz(sort([1:4:nnz(val) 2:4:nnz(val)]));
```

To remove make the non-desired values within `val`:

```
ind = find(val);
val(ind(sort([3:4:numel(ind) 4:4:numel(ind)]))) = 0;
```